# What's the correct datetime format for a century in the HTML time element?

Tags: html, time, semantic-markup

I wanted to use it to represent a century as a period of time, what would be a correct format for the `datetime` attribute using the HTML `<time>` element?

Example:

```html
In the <time datetime="???">20th century</time> things changed a lot.
```

Correct me, please, if this is not a correct usage of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what the `time` element is for. `datetime` must specify a specific point in time, or a specific duration of time. There's not a way to specify "100 years starting on this date".

Comment: Wouldn't "100 tears from this date" be a specific duration of time?

Comment: Sorry, that "tears" was a typo, I meant "years"

Comment: "100 years" would be a specific duration, but "100 years from this date" is more information than just a duration. `datetime` doesn't provide a mechanism for denoting _which_ 100 years